# CSS classes for Gutenberg buttons block are not applying on frontend

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm experiencing a problem with the buttons block in Gutenberg. When I make changes to the layout in the editor I can see them applied there, but on the frontend no classes are added.
The only way I interfere with the default behavior of blocks in the theme is by adding new buttons with `wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle('core/button', {});`. I've tried removing my code that affects the behavior of blocks, but it didn't change the situation. Do I need to add any additional code to support this feature?

[Screenshot from the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSNZe.jpg)
[Screenshot of the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJJCl.jpg)

Comment: After making the changes to the button alignment in the Editor, have you saved/published the post before checking the frontend? Does your site use any caching plugin?

Comment: Yes, I saved these changes. I don't use any caching plugins.

This issue appeared on several projects where I was creating a theme from scratch. Most Gutenberg blocks work without any additional coding needed, except for buttons.

Comment: In your themes you've created from scratch, do you have `add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );` in your functions.php?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've checked and I don't have this line in my theme, but the "wp-block-library-css" is supported by default ([screenshot](https://imgsh.net/a/NseEVbc.png)). I tried adding "wp-block-styles" as you've mentioned and it didn't fix the problem for me, though it added the "classic theme" to my styles ([screenshot](https://imgsh.net/a/U795pyD.png))

Comment: Thanks for confirming. To help figure out what could be the issue, could you please add to your question what version of WordPress you are testing against and any plugins are enabled?

Comment: For my latest project where I'm facing this issue, I use WordPress 6.1.1, but the problem also appeared with earlier versions. The only plugin active on this project is Advanced Custom Fields PRO which I use for building custom Gutenberg blocks. My theme doesn't use the new JSON-based structure used in the latest default themes that come with the installation pack, it still runs the old PHP-based structure. Can it be the cause of the problem?